# How can I browse web site after login using https/http protocol(in Java)

Tags: java, http, https

I'm trying to login web site using Java and I succeeded. Below is the code I used.

```
    String query = "myquery";
    URL url = new URL(loginUrl);
    HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-length", String.valueOf(query.length()));
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.0;Windows98;DigExt)");
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    con.setDoInput(true);

    DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());

    output.writeBytes(query);
    output.close();

    DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream( con.getInputStream() );

    for( int c = input.read(); c != -1; c = input.read() ) {
       System.out.print( (char)c );
       // this page returns JavaScript code
    }
```

After this, I want to access another web page in same domain, so I tried below code.

```
    URL url = new URL(anotherUrl);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    ... similar to above code ...
```

But this page asks me to login again. I think connection has been disconnected in the process of changing URL. (Onlt login page uses `HTTPS` protocol and other pages use `HTTP` protocol)

How can I fix this?
Someone please help

Comment: You used Https for the first connection then Http for the second one. Why would you expect to maintain connection state?

Comment: Sorry I missed it. Only login page uses HTTPS and other pages use HTTP. So I'm confused...

Comment: What happens if you access the website from a web browser? Does it change from HTTPS to HTTP? Do you remain logged in?

Comment: It looks like the web server uses some kind of session with HTTP cookies. In this case you need to store the cookies from first (login) response and pass it to second request.

Comment: Yes it changes from HTTPS HTTP remaining login state. When login succeed, it redirects page. (from http://abc.example.com/login to http://abc2.example.com, abc domain changes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep in mind that HTTP is completely stateless. The idea of "logging in" to a site translates to (usually) setting cookies from an HTTP perspective. Those cookies are simply HTTP headers and they are sent with each subsequent request by your browser. So for you to maintain the logged in state its up to you get the cookies from the response headers and send them along with future requests.

Here is how:

**Retrieving cookies from a response:**

Open a java.net.URLConnection to the server:

```
URL myUrl = new URL("http://www.hccp.org/cookieTest.jsp");
URLConnection urlConn = myUrl.openConnection();
urlConn.connect();
```

Loop through response headers looking for cookies:
Since a server may set multiple cookies in a single request, we will need to loop through the response headers, looking for all headers named "Set-Cookie".

```
String headerName=null;
for (int i=1; (headerName = uc.getHeaderFieldKey(i))!=null; i++) {
   if (headerName.equals("Set-Cookie")) {                  
    String cookie = urlConn.getHeaderField(i);               
    ...
```

**Extract cookie name and value from cookie string:**
The string returned by the getHeaderField(int index) method is a series of name=value separated by semi-colons (;). The first name/value pairing is actual data string we are interested in (i.e. "sessionId=0949eeee22222rtg" or "userId=igbrown"), the subsequent name/value pairings are meta-information that we would use to manage the storage of the cookie (when it expires, etc.).

```
    cookie = cookie.substring(0, cookie.indexOf(";"));
    String cookieName = cookie.substring(0, cookie.indexOf("="));
    String cookieValue = cookie.substring(cookie.indexOf("=") + 1, cookie.length());
```

This is basically it. We now have the cookie name (cookieName) and the cookie value (cookieValue).

Setting a cookie value in a request:

Values must be set prior to calling the connect method:

```
 URL myUrl = new URL("http://www.hccp.org/cookieTest.jsp");
    URLConnection urlConn = myUrl.openConnection();
```

Create a cookie string:

```
String myCookie = "userId=igbrown";
```

Add the cookie to a request:
Using the

setRequestProperty(String name, String value);

method, we will add a property named "Cookie", passing the cookie string created in the previous step as the property value.

```
urlConn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", myCookie);
```

Send the cookie to the server:
To send the cookie, simply call connect() on the URLConnection for which we have added the cookie property:

```
 urlConn.connect()
```

Comment: [link]http://www.hccp.org/java-net-cookie-how-to.html
Thank you for answer. To add cookies to request, setRequestProperty() method should not be used more than one time. (Add cookies using setRequestProperty() method at once)